# Invalid combination of Swagger & Jackson dependencies?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, apache-camel, swagger

This is where it goes wrong:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
    at io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver.resolve(ModelResolver.java:425)
```

Digging a bit deeper, the failing line @ ModelResolver.java:425 is:

```
JavaType propType = member.getType(beanDesc.bindingsForBeanType());
```

`member`, is a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember` where `getType()` has no arguments.

I'm using Apache Camel Spring Boot starters like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Camel & Spring versions are:

```
<camel.version>3.4.2</camel.version>
<spring-boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

This pulls in Jackson jars at v2.11.10 and Swagger jars at v1.5.24, except swagger-parser which is v1.0.47.

[image: swagger jars]

[image: jackson jars]

So there seems to be an invalid combination of Swagger & Jackson dependencies.

**Update 1**

Here is the entire pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>yyyyyyyyyyyyy.io</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyyy-integration-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.artifactId>yyyy-integration</project.artifactId>
        <!-- latest versions @ Jul 2020 -->
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.4.2</camel.version>    <!-- 3.4.x is latest long term support version -->
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <!-- Salesforce Rest API version: GET https://xxxxxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/ -->
        <camel-sfdc.apiVersion>49.0</camel-sfdc.apiVersion>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <run.profiles>dev</run.profiles>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!--Import as a pom to let spring-boot to manage spring-boot dependency 
                versions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!--Import as a pom to let camel to manage camel-spring-boot dependency 
                versions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- Camel Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data format: JSON [un]marshalling using Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Not in List of Starters https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/list.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Send requests to external HTTP servers using Apache HTTP Client 4.x. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Salesforce -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-salesforce-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Allows triggering events at specific time intervals -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cron-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Log messages to the underlying logging mechanism. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-log-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Perform SQL queries using Spring JDBC. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-sql-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Component: Access databases through SQL and JDBC. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Deployment to Tomcat: see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy -->
        <!--Spring boot dependencies to enable WEB and TOMCAT features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- removes embedded Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Component: To create REST services using REST DSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Use Swagger with Rest DSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-openapi-java-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Component: Serve HTTP requests by a Servlet. -->
        <!-- in conjunction with restConfiguration().component("camel-servlet") -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--Spring boot dependencies to enable JDBC features -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- Component: Expose HTTP endpoints using the HTTP server available in the current platform. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-platform-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- data type: CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-csv-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use CXF HTTP transport to run Camel in Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Needed for Hawtio to detect Camel Context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL JDBC connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.20</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SQL Server JDBC driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.2.jre11</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from .../camel-in-action-2/chapter9/spring-boot-test-one-route/pom.xml -->
        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Java Configuration
        See https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/others/spring-javaconfig.html
        See https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-spring-javaconfig/pom.xml
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for jsonschema2pojo generated classes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-mail</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- for creating salesforce POJOs/DTOs -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-salesforce-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version> <!--  should come from pom? -->
                <configuration>
                    <clientId>${camel-sfdc.clientId}</clientId>
                    <clientSecret>${camel-sfdc.clientSecret}</clientSecret>
                    <userName>${camel-sfdc.userName}</userName>
                    <password>${camel-sfdc.password}</password>
                    <loginUrl default-value="https://login.salesforce.com">${camel-sfdc.loginUrl}</loginUrl>
                    <useStringsForPicklists>true</useStringsForPicklists><!-- still generates enums, though not referenced -->
                    <!-- does nothing in Camel 3.4.2 jsonSchema>true</jsonSchema --><!-- true to generate json schema instead of DTOs, default is false -->
                    
                    <!-- xxxxxxxxx -->
                    <version>${camel-sfdc.apiVersion}</version>
                    <packageName>yyyy.model.sfdc.xxxxxxxxx</packageName>
                    <includes>
                        <include>Account</include>
                        <include>Invoice__c</include>
                        <include>Opportunity</include>
                        <include>OpportunityLineItem</include>
                        <include>OpportunitySplit</include>
                        <include>OpportunitySplitType</include>
                        <include>Product2</include>
                        <include>User</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                  <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                 </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Update 2**

REST config

```
        restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")    // FIXME 10 "camel-servlet" (when running in Tomcat or WildFly) raises: No bean could be found in the registry for: camel-servlet of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestApiConsumerFactory
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
            .scheme("http") // TODO 10 https scheme - requires cert?
            .contextPath("api")
//          .apiContextPath("api-doc")  // FIXME 10 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember.getType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeBindings;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .clientRequestValidation(true)
        ;
```

**Update 3**

```
2020-09-08 15:04:24.015 ERROR 15200 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: Failed to start route oauth.refreshTokens.get because of null

org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route oauth.refreshTokens.get because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:125) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:263) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:156) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:114) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2809) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2657) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2620) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2452) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121) ~[camel-spring-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:157) ~[camel-spring-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at c10y.camel.ScratchTestApp.main(ScratchTestApp.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: openapi of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestConsumerFactory
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestEndpoint.createConsumer(RestEndpoint.java:470) ~[camel-rest-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.addServices(DefaultRoute.java:560) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:166) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    ... 26 common frames omitted

2020-09-08 15:04:24.023  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.4.2 (camel-1) is shutting down
2020-09-08 15:04:24.263  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.4.2 (camel-1) uptime 1.030 seconds
2020-09-08 15:04:24.271  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.4.2 (camel-1) is shutdown in 0.248 seconds
2020-09-08 15:04:24.986  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-09-08 15:04:24.988  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.s.CamelHttpTransportServlet      : Destroyed CamelHttpTransportServlet[CamelServlet]
2020-09-08 15:04:25.235  INFO 15200 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-09-08 15:04:25.241 ERROR 15200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route oauth.refreshTokens.get because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:125) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:263) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:156) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:114) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2809) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2657) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2620) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2452) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121) ~[camel-spring-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:157) ~[camel-spring-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at c10y.camel.ScratchTestApp.main(ScratchTestApp.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: openapi of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestConsumerFactory
    at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestEndpoint.createConsumer(RestEndpoint.java:470) ~[camel-rest-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.addServices(DefaultRoute.java:560) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:166) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.4.2.jar:3.4.2]
    ... 26 common frames omitted

2020-09-08 15:04:25.258  INFO 15200 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: There is a camel-openapi-java-starter that should replace the swagger starter, can you try with it ?

Comment: Having the openapi starter now gives this error, which prevents Camel from starting:
`Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such as the camel-openapi-java component)`. Yet, RestApiProcessorFactory exists in camel-api.3.42.jar. Is something else required in `restConfiguration()`? Wrt. API all I have is `.apiContextPath("api-doc")`.

Comment: you need to add a component that can be used by the rest dsl such as camel-undertow undertow or as you are using spring, camel-servlet (in that case you also need the spring boot web starters)

Comment: I tried `restConfiguration().component("camel-servlet")` along with `camel-servlet-starter` pom dependency before raising my question here, but received a similar registry error: `No bean could be found in the registry for: camel-servlet of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestApiConsumerFactory`. I have updated my question with the full pom in the hope that helps.

Comment: restConfiguration().component("camel-servlet")  --> restConfiguration().component("servlet")

Comment: I've updated my question to include the full restConfiguration(). I tried `component("camel-servlet")` before posting my question, but reverted to `component("servlet")` due to the 'no bean found' error detailed in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't get if it is working on not

Comment: It's not working using `restConfiguration().component("servlet")` with camel-rest-starter, camel-openapi-java-starter, & camel-servlet-starter pom dependencies. It's the same `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath` error.

Comment: any chance to provide a small reproducer ?

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli Certainly. Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wSuR-xz0kcde3fNMmSiQdG47DiuzDh_K/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: can you create a repo on github ? I don't have permission to download from gdrive and collaborating on github would be much easier

Comment: I think there's some wrong default somewhere, can you set apiComponent("openapi")

Comment: @LucaBurgazzoli Here's the repo: https://github.com/suitej/camel-openapi-reproducer.git. I tried `apiComponent("openapi")` but it raises the same kind of error: `Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: openapi of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestApiConsumerFactory`

Comment: I've updated your example to use openpai as suggested and I don't see any issue, sent also a PR https://github.com/suitej/camel-openapi-reproducer/pull/1

Comment: Baffling! I pulled your changes, then in Eclipse cleaned the project and reran the app only to received the same error. Are you running it differently? I've update my question with the full stack trace.

Comment: mvn spring-boot:run from the command line

Comment: I still get the same error from the command line. I guess I have an environment issue - Java 11 on Windows 10. I'll try running it in a Ubuntu VM when I get the chance. In the mean time I'll have to do without OpenAPI. Thanks for all your help @LucaBurgazzoli.

Comment: we can have a chat tomorrow on gitter

Comment: Sure. Please let me know how. Thanks.

Comment: Have you reached a solution to this issue? If so please paste it here for the world to see.